# How do I check if an unowned reference is deallocated in my unit tests?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, memory-management

My view model is as such:

```
public class MainTabBarViewModel: MainTabBarInputs {
    unowned var output: MainTabBarOutputs
    ...
}
```

where the view controller is this:

```
class ViewController: MainTabBarOutputs {
    var viewModel: MainTabBarInputs!
}
```

I'm trying to write a unit test to test for the retain cycle:

```
class MainTabBarViewModelTests: XCTestCase {

    var viewModel: MainTabBarViewModel!
    var viewController: MockMainTabBarViewController!

    func testRetainViewController() {
        viewController = nil
        // TODO how do you test this
        expect(self.viewModel.output).to(beNil())
        // crashes because I can't 
        // reference an unowned pointer that's deallocated.
    }
```

I know if I changed my reference to be `weak` I could test this, but what if I wanted to leave it as `unowned`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836745/does-arc-hold-a-count-for-unowned-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a weak reference to the controller in the unit test, and if that reference becomes nil, then you don't have a retain cycle:

```swift
func testRetainViewController() {
    weak var testRef = viewController
    viewController = nil
    expect(testRef).to(beNil())
}
```

You can easily validate the above approach by changing from `unowned` to `strong` and see that the test fails.